# Relative etch rates of nitric acid on metals and oxides

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, metal, reference-request

I am trying to either find or calculate the etch rate of nitric acid ($\ce{HNO3}$) for various different metals and oxides. The ones I am interested in are titanium ($\ce{Ti}$), zirconium ($\ce{Zr}$), and lead ($\ce{Pb}$); and their oxides $\ce{TiO2}$, $\ce{ZrO2}$, and $\ce{PbO/PbO2}$.

I have checked lots of sources, including the *CRC Handbook of Metal Etchants*, and have not been able to find anything that describes comparative etch rates for those six materials. Where can I find this information or, alternatively, how can I estimate these quantitites?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/microeng/processing/etching/Miscellaneous%2520Etchants.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwivwpSygafKAhWDcI4KHc_dA58QFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNF8sWBMUoyiGyij78SanpYYzFnuxg&sig2=3zP6ANYmFvCK8rK2jj2qIw

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.chemcut.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Etching-Titanium-with-HF-and-Nitric-Acid-Solutions-Part1.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjvhaClgafKAhURjo4KHU5FA6MQFggZMAA&usg=AFQjCNHgsxipDmDaCMz8LvtrjPkjYJNa1Q&sig2=GiK_mnUAtpSpZygJegy2Hg